# How to find the limiting sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n (\pi)^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$

I know that this series converges, but the only limiting sum formula I know is the for the geometric series.  However, I am unable to rewrite this as a geometric series.  Could anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: What geometric series? Your sum equals $\cos \pi = - 1$.

Comment: Use the Taylor series for $\cos x$.

Comment: @IttayWeiss, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taylor expansion of cosine is give by
$$\cos(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}$$
substitute $x=\pi$